# High memory usage on server after upgrading from MySQL to MariaDB

Tags: memory, memory-usage, mariadb

I recently upgraded from MySQL 5.5 to MariaDB 10.0. After upgrading, rebuilding Apache & PHP, I noticed that memory usage went up by around 200+ MB. I have a VPS of 2 GB available. Before the upgrade, free memory was around 825 MB. However, after MariaDB installed the memory became around 600 MB. I'm not 100% sure if MariaDB was the reason for the higher memory usage or not.

Here is my top command output:

```
Tasks:  46 total,   1 running,  45 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   2097152k total,  1476880k used,   620272k free,        0k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,   339012k cached

PID USER      PR  NI  USED  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
  831 mysql     20   0 66892  65m 8540 S  0.3  3.2   0:00.61 mysqld
  905 root      20   0 56312  54m 3336 S  0.0  2.7   0:01.19 /usr/local/cpan
  906 root      20   0 54172  52m 1188 S  0.0  2.6   0:00.00 spamd child
1104 root      20   0 29276  28m 1508 S  0.0  1.4   0:00.06 cpsrvd (SSL) -
1188 root      20   0 22500  21m  560 S  0.0  1.1   0:00.00 cpdavd - accept
  954 nobody    20   0 22056  21m  740 S  0.0  1.1   0:00.00 nginx
  655 root      20   0 21120  20m 1768 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.47 lfd - sleeping
1122 root      20   0 20612  20m 1224 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.00 dnsadmin - serv
1165 root      20   0 16656  16m 1232 S  0.0  0.8   0:00.19 tailwatchd
1031 root      20   0 11428  11m 2896 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.06 leechprotect
1111 root      20   0  7312 7312 1564 S  0.0  0.3   0:00.02 queueprocd - wa
  916 root      20   0  6404 6404 4408 S  0.0  0.3   0:00.03 httpd
1199 root      38  18  6100 6100  788 S  0.0  0.3   0:00.00 cpanellogd - sl
1033 nobody    20   0  4740 4740 2268 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.00 httpd
1032 nobody    20   0  3928 3928 1544 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.00 httpd
  892 dovenull  20   0  3656 3656 2748 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.01 imap-login
1123 root      20   0  3532 3532 2732 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.04 sshd
```

I feel that output is illogical. At the beginning of the result it shows 1476880k used which is 1476 MB. If I summed up each process usage plus the cached memory, the result will be much lower than 1400+ MB. From where this memory usage come from?

Any suggestions please? Thank you :)

Comment: The output _is_ illogical since your system is not an actual machine or even a normal virtual machine but a container (probably OpenVZ). Anyway since MariaDB is only using 65MB it can't possibly account for a 200MB discrepancy. If you want to free up RAM, try getting rid of that cPanel junk.

Comment: So, that might be a memory overselling by the vps provider? Thank you @MichaelHampton

Comment: I suspect you might be getting access to _more_ memory than you paid for, based on my previous knowledge of OpenVZ. But as a general rule I don't think the bad parts of OpenVZ outweigh the good parts...

Comment: @JFallz This seems relevant (I'm seeing 300MB usage but 2GB commit for my local development machine where only I use it ever), if this helps @ John back at my please: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/myisam-system-variables/#key_buffer_size